# Powerpoint VBA runtime error 424 object required

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm attempting to create a simple PowerPoint with some VBA in it in order to make it an interactive quiz.

```
Sub CorrectAnswer()
Points.Caption = (Points.Caption) + 10
Output = MsgBox("Your answer is correct, well done!", vbOKOnly, "Correct     Answer")
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub IncorrectAnswer()
Points.Caption = (Points.Caption) - 0
Output = MsgBox("Your answer is wrong.", vbOKOnly, "Wrong Answer")
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub FIB1()
    Dim answer As String

    answer = InputBox(Prompt:="Type your code below")
    If answer = "test response" Then
        CorrectAnswer
    Else
        IncorrectAnswer
    End If
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub


Sub Reset()
Points.Caption = 0
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
End Sub
```

In the Sub FIB1 area is where I'm getting the problems.  It gives me the runtime error '424' stating object not referenced.  What I am wanting this to do is it asks a question, and they click on a button/link on the slide and it opens a dialog box where you can type in your answer.  At that point they click OK, and if they typed it in right, they get the correct answer.  If not, of course they get the incorrect answer.

This is meant to be the fill-in-the-blank type of setup, instead of the multiple choice style, which I also have in there and is working fine.  This seems to be the only area giving me an issue.  I don't know enough VBA to see what I'm doing wrong and most of this code has come from watching videos on youtube to put it together.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, declare all your variables with an explicit type. What specific instruction is throwing the error exactly? Error 424 is "object required", not "object not referenced". You're making a member call against something that isn't an object, in all likelihood an implicit `Variant`.

Comment: What is Points?  An ActiveX label or the like?  If so, you need to get a reference to the object and set the caption differently:  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Points").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "whatever"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Do you mean to put that on the top of everything, or just the FIB1 area?  Also, you are right, it does say "object required" and not "object not referenced".  I remembered incorrectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Points is just that, the points the person will have at the end of the test, out of 100.

Comment: `Option Explicit` goes at the very top of the module, in the *declarations* section. Better yet, go to Tools > Options, and check the "require variable declaration" checkbox, so that the VBE automatically adds it everywhere for you.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I tried that and still error 424.  What's above is my entire code setup, so if I'm missing other parts, let me know.  Like I said, just trying to piece this together.

Comment: @user3072193 "Points is just that, the points the person will have at the end of the test, out of 100" ... that may be what it represents, but it's clearly an object of some sort. What sort of object IS it?

Comment: Maybe I would do better to ask how either of you would program this?  It's to be an interactive quiz where multiple choice slides are available, as well as "fill in the blank".  I don't mind admitting I'm a newb, but this is what I had come up with.  I don't know enough to answer your question unfortunately @SteveRindsberg

Comment: @RoJo You're trying to set the .Caption property of Points to a string value. That suggests that it's an ActiveX object ... ie, a TextBox or other object that you've inserted using the Developer tab. What type of object is it in fact? Also, on what line does the error occur?